# Where can I find a free Java Library to read multiple email formats

Tags: gratis, library, java, email

Our team has used Aspose .NET in the past (a product we purchased) to read multiple versions of email messages and parse the information for their content.  We now want to to do a similar thing in Java.  As opposed to buying a new Java license, we would like to consider what free Java programs there are out there to do such a thing.

So my request is:

1. Free
2. Java library
3. Multiple email formats handled
4. Read/Parse emails
5. Similar functionality to Aspose if possible

---

Taking it straight from the our requirement list, here are the required email file formats:

- Outlook PST
- Outlook OST
- Outlook Express DBX
- Plain-test MBOX
- AOL PFC

Comment: What email formats specifically does it need to support?